# Vuejs, Dynamic b-table with editable fields and two-way databinding

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, generic-programming, bootstrap-vue, two-way-binding

I'm trying to generate a dynamic b-table with editable fields and with two-way databinding.

I would like to not have any hardcoded values. Now, I have:

```
<b-table striped hover :items="filtered">
    <template v-slot:cell(issueDescription)="row">
      <b-form-input v-model="row.item.issueDescription" />
    </template>
    <template v-slot:cell(endTime)="row">
      <b-form-input v-model="row.item.endTime" />
    </template>
    <template v-slot:cell(startTime)="row">
      <b-form-input v-model="row.item.startTime" />
    </template>
</b-table>
```

Where:

```
filtered = [ { "issueDescription": "this is a description", "endTime": "2020-02-11T14:00:00.000Z", 
"startTime": "2020-02-11T01:24:00.000Z" }]
```

If I generate template with a v-for, then I got editable fields in every column, but no binding at each field.

```
<b-table striped hover :items="filtered">
    <template v-for="x in filtered" v-slot:cell()="row">
      <b-form-input v-model="row.item.BIND_TO_SPECIFIC_TABLE_ROW_COL" />
    </template>
</b-table>
```

How do I bind to the specific row,col??

I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfhu1owt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have ALL fields editable, you can use this syntax.

```html
<template v-slot:cell()="{ item, field: { key } }">
  <b-form-input v-model="item[key]" />
</template>
```

It's pretty similar to what you had. You just needed to use the `key` from the slot context object. (I've shorthanded it a bit, but it's the same as going `row.field.key`).
Also note that i don't use a `v-for` in the template, this is because `v-slot:cell()` is a fallback slot which is valid for all slots unless a specific one is defined. For example `v-slot:cell(issueDescription)` would overwrite `v-slot:cell()` for the `issueDescription` field.

While the above works, the problem might come one day when you have a field you DONT want to be editable, like maybe an `id` field in your object.

To solve this issue, I've defined my fields and passed them to the table. I've also added a `editable` property to the fields i want to be editable. (note this is not a standard thing in the field object, but something specific for you use-case).

I then created a computed property `editableFields` which returns all fields that have `editable: true`, and then use `editableFields` in my `v-for` inside `b-table`.

This way you can pick and choose which properties you want to be editable in your objects.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    editableFields() {
      return this.fields.filter(field => field.editable)
    }
  },
  data: {
    filtered: [
      { 
        "id": "1",
        "issueDescription": "this is a description", 
        "endTime": "2020-02-11T14:00:00.000Z", 
        "startTime": "2020-02-11T01:24:00.000Z" 
      },
      { 
        "id": "2",
        "issueDescription": "this is a description", 
        "endTime": "2020-02-11T14:00:00.000Z", 
        "startTime": "2020-02-11T01:24:00.000Z" 
      }
    ],
    fields: [
      { key: 'id', label: 'ID' },
      { key: 'issueDescription', label: 'Issue Description', editable: true },
      { key: 'startTime', label: 'Start Time', editable: true },
      { key: 'endTime', label: 'End Time', editable: true }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.4.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.4.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <b-table :items="filtered" :fields="fields">
    <template v-for="field in editableFields" v-slot:[`cell(${field.key})`]="{ item }">
      <b-input v-model="item[field.key]"/>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answar! It works :-)